# Creating a class with attributes of this class type + inheritance to other class (Node classs and NodeAVL)

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to do the following code:

```
class Node
{
    protected:
        int *value;
        Node *leftChild;
        Node *rightChild;
        friend class BST;

    public:
        Node(int value = 0);
        virtual ~Node();
        virtual int info();
};

Node::Node(int value) : leftChild(nullptr), rightChild(nullptr) {
    this->value = new int(value);
    std::cout << "Creating the node " << *(this->value) << "\n";
}

class NodeAVL : public Node
{
    private:
        friend class AVL;
    public:
        int *balanceFactor;
        NodeAVL(int value = 0);
        virtual ~NodeAVL();
};

NodeAVL::NodeAVL(int value) : Node(value) {
    this->balanceFactor = new int(0);
    std::cout << "Creating the AVL node " << *(this->value) << " with balance factor " << *(this->balanceFactor) << "\n";
}
```

Now, my problem is that I should derive NodeAVL (mandatory), and I have a problem with the Node class (base class), because there are declarations of `Node *leftChild` and `Node *rightChild`, and when I create an AVL node, it creates its children of type `Node*`. How can I create it with the type `NodeAVL*`? 
Or how can I create a class T like:

```
class T{
    T* leftChild;
    T* rightChild;
}
```

so that I would have `Node` class have `Node` children and `NodeAVL` which is derived from `Node` have `NodeAVL` children?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged your post with polymorphism I will give you a runtime polymorphism based answer. You don't.

*Part of the point* of runtime polymorphism is that an object dervied from the base class can be passed and stored *as* an object of the base class while still retaining its overriden functionality (Yes slicing is an issue but we are dealing with pointers here). Therefore you do not need `Node` to be changed to `NodeAVL`, simply setting `leftChild` or `rightChild` to point at an object of `NodeAVL` instead of `Node` is enough, any overriden methods will call the method in `NodeAVL`.

You are setting your nodes to `nullptr` anyway but if you didn't then you could make a `Node` contructor which takes pointers for `leftChild` and `rightChild` (possibly make it protected so only derived classes can use it).

As a side note use your initaliser list to set `value` instead of setting it afterwards. Also prefer smart pointers to naked pointers.

Comment: Well, I agree with you. But the thing is, if I try to change the value of balancedFactor from the NodeAVL, I can’t if the leftChild or rightChild is a Node* type.

Comment: In that case you have not implemented a polymorphic base class, like I said in the beginning this answer assumes you are using runtime polymorphism. If `NodeAVL` is-a (what public inheritance means) `Node` then it _has_ to have at least the same attributes as a `Node`, changing the type of one of those attributes means `NodeAVL` is no longer useable as a `Node`.

Comment: Ok, but is there a way then to make NodeAVL of type Node, but to have the children of type NodeAVL, as I asked in the question?

Comment: No. You cannot derive from a class and change the type of one it its members. Like I said above that completely breaks the idea of inheritance in the first place, redesign your code. You could do this with templates except you are trying to store a member of the then templated class (templating itself), causing an endless cycle as you try and declare it's type. (Templates don't break inheritance as you inherit from a _specific form_ of the parent)

Comment: Could you help me with templates then? I’m not really into them

Comment: Templates won't fix this problem. Also if you want to learn templates pick up a book or google around and try them out yourself.